# Looping through JQuery Id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have the task of setting the border color of inputs fields by error to red using jquery. I did it but i don't wanna be repeating myself. Is there any way to make it shorter and also how to set the color to green when values are entered in the input fields. Thnx

Javascript Code

```
if (err !== 0){

    $("#inputOne").css("border-color", "red");
    $("#inputTwo").css("border-color", "red");
    $("#inputThree").css("border-color", "red");
    $("#inputFour").css("border-color", "red");

    //If there are errors, alert the user and return false
    $.notify("Please fill fields with *!",
        {
            position: 'bottom right',

        }
    );
    return false;
}
```

I tried $("#inputOne", "#inputTwo", "#inputThree", "#inputFour").css("border-color", "red");   but did not work

Comment: Milind has answered the question correctly, but when you want to group elements together like that, a class is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
$("#inputOne,#inputTwo,#inputThree,#inputFour").css("border-color", "red");
```

Note how the CSS selector is *one string*. Just like CSS rules in a stylesheet, you can use the comma to separate multiple selectors to match.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks. any idea what `$("#inputOne", "#inputTwo", "#inputThree", "#inputFour")` will select? i think it is incorrect syntax.

Comment: It's incorrect, yes. Unless `#inputOne` is *inside* `#inputTwo`, it won't select anything. If `#inputOne` were inside `#inputTwo`, it would select that. The `$` function is ridiculously overloaded, but the variant it picks when given four strings is [this one](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context): `jQuery(selector, context)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting each class in separate quotes put all the class in single quote.

Try this:

```
$("#inputOne, #inputTwo, #inputThree, #inputFour").css("border-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can change the selector names you can do it like this.

```
var numberOFinputs = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOFinputs; i++) {
     $("#input_"+i).css("border-color", "red");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this and not making a `validator` for your inputs?

It works like you said with multiple selectors between `(` and `)`, but you have to put them like this:

```
 $('#el1,#el2,#el3')   // note that I don't have multiple strings between parantheses, just one
```

You can also combine different types of selectors :

```
$("#el1,.el2,input[name='test']")
```

See [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/nL3kaksw/2/) fiddle

If you want to build up a 'validator' without using a plugin, a simple one could look like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var isValid=true;
    var error;

    $('form input').each(function(){
      var $el=$(this);
      var elementData = $el.data();
      var value = $el.val();

      if(elementData.isRequired){
        // do something here
      }

      if(elementData.minLength){
       // do something here
      }
   });

});




<form>

 FirstName:<input type='text' name='FirstName' data-isrequired='true' /> <br />
 LastName: <input type='text' name='LastName' data-isrequired='true' /> <br />
 UserName: <input type='text' name='Username' data-isrequired='true'  data-minLength='3'/> <br />

<input type='submit' value='Validate'/>

</form>
```

Note the code above is something very simple which can be improved a lot. It's used only for this question, as an example.